# Is changing background color in unix through .profile is possible?

Tags: profile

I am using Unix and accessing it through putty. I have saved IP address, color, font and other attributes in putty. But whenever I am sitting on other PC then I have to again change all this attributes.

Is it possible to save these changes in User .profile so that it will be reflected once I open's any session.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: tty setb [1-7] will set the color as sequired

Answer (score 0):

PuTTY stores your customizations (IP-addresses, user-login information, colors) in the Windows registry's "CURRENT_USER" area (settings applying to *you* when you log in).

You can save those settings to a file (export) and restore (import) them on any Windows machine you use.  To do the export, you use the `regedit` command, usually from a console window.  `regedit` without parameters runs a graphical user interface which makes it easy to navigate to this tree

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions
```

Right-click, export to file, e.g., `putty.reg`.

To import, you need only "open" the file from your desktop.  You can also use `regedit`, but that is a needless step.

For discussion:

- [How to export PUTTY Sessions list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13023920/how-to-export-putty-sessions-list)
- [How to Transfer PuTTY Sessions To Another Windows Machine](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/putty-session.html)
- [Export And Import Putty Registry Settings](http://www.allguru.net/error-solution/export-import-putty-registry-settings/)